# one script using many files

Tags: bash, scripting

I would like to execute many jobs by one script in bash. I did two and I cannot execute more. I did it one by one.
The following procedure is: `./script /directory fileX`. When in the directory are files which script is using to calculate the compatibility of values from fileX.

e.g. `./script ./directory file1&` and then as a second `./script ./directory file1 &`

I would like to do from file 1 to e.g file 10.

Is it possible to do it? If yes, please help.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done via `for` loop for example

```
for i in $(seq 1 10)
do
./script ./directory file$i &
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Bash3+ with brace expansion.

```
for i in {1..10}; do
  /script ./directory "file$i" &
done
```

With POSIX `sh`

```
i=1
while [ "$i" -le 10 ]; do
  /script ./directory "file$i" &
i=$((i + 1))
done
```

Comment: you should start with `i=1` and while check should be `-le 10`. otherwise you will do it till 9. Or you can change  the places of `/script.....` and `i=$((.....` lines

Comment: @RomeoNinov, thank you for that wonderful comment, but if you start counting from zero until nine you still manage to run the code 10 times right?

Comment: But the OP want from 1, not 10 times :)

Comment: @RomeoNinov, right How did I missed that ... :-(, updated the answer.